# is it possible to generate jquery datepicker from behind / C#?

Tags: asp.net

I am working with asp.net and i have some question here, any help will be great.I am trying to generate controls from Codebehind(C#) since the amount of data which is returned from server is uncertain, now my question is, is it possible to generate **jquery datepicker** control from C#?  how to do that? show me some examples.

thank you.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47474/ASP-NET-Control-from-jQuery-DatePicker-in-3-Minute

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible . You can have a common class which you want to use for Date Picker while creating your control add the class on the textbox on the server side.

```
            txt.Attributes.Add("class", "myCal");
```

On the client side call this javascript

```
     $(doucment).ready(function(){
        $(".myCal").datepicker();
     });
```

This will loop through all the textboxes with myCal as class and will it make it into datePicker

Answer (score 0):

you may check [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to learn and see the sample codes of datepickers. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Codebehind**:

```
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "datepicker";
    div1.Controls.Add(txt);
```

If u want for more number of textboxes u can use cssclass instead of id.

```
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.cssclass = "date";
    div1.Controls.Add(txt);
```

**Aspx**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();//or $(".date").datepicker(); for more number of textboxes
  });
</script>
```

Add required scripts and styles in aspx as well.To know more see this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: but it will limit scope because you have to add the javascript code for each control name , so if you create on the fly it will not work in all the cases until you javascript part is also dynamic. That's why I thought class will help

Comment: ya u r right mate.U can use cssclass if u want to create more textboxes and add datetime picker..